# render component base on the type of a non primitive variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I've got a issue since a long time that I can't find how to resolve. I would like to check the type of a variable, if it's one type do something else do something else.

In this exemple I use typeof which is of course not possible but to give an idea of what I would like to do.

I would like to render a different component base on the type of button

```ts
type Type01 = {
  path: string;
  label: string;
};

type ComponentTestType = {
  button: Type01 | "default" | JSX.Element;
};

export function ComponentTest({ button }: ComponentTestType) {
  if (typeof button === "default") {
    //render something
  } else if (typeof button === Type01) {
    //render something else
  }
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Typescript types compile away, they have no runtime reification, and relatedly there's no type-based dispatch. You'll have to duck type it by checking the properties of button.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this will do the job.

```
type Type01 = {
  path: string;
  label: string;
};

type ComponentTestType = {
  button: Type01 | "default" | JSX.Element;
};

function isType01(button: any): button is Type01 {
  return typeof button === 'object' && 'path' in button && 'label' in button;
}

export function ComponentTest({ button }: ComponentTestType) {
  if (button === "default") {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  } else if (isType01(button)) {
    return <div>Hi</div>
  } else {
    return <div>XIX</div>
  }
}
```

[Check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-tdd-t6zkr6?file=/src/ComponentTest.tsx)